# Do I tell a user to approve my answer?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

I haven't found anything like this in Stack Overflow's code of conduct. However, a new contributor indicated on his question that my answer worked for him under the answer comment section and upvoted the answer, But he did not approve the answer. Is it okay to let him know that if it works he should mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Are you seriously bringing gender into this because OP referred to the other person as "he" and "him"? Focus on the question at hand, not completely irrelevant linguistic issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Has that user ever accepted any other answers? If so they know how to and you shouldn't cajole them into accepting your answer if they know perfectly well how to but choose not to.

If they've never accepted anything then it's possible they're unaware of accepting or how to do it so you might mention to them the fact that it's something that's possible and how you'd go about it but again, it's their choice whether or not they accept your (or any) answer.

Comment: That is the user's first post which means, no they haven't, What's the best way to politely ask without being awkward

Comment: @none: one way is to post a simple comment, one without any acceptance request: "Please have a look at this section from the help site: [someone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)." You aren't telling them what to do, only suggesting that they look at what the *site* suggests that they may do.